# What exactly does _force_close_ do in aiohttp (Base)Connector?

Tags: sockets, request, aiohttp

From the [aiohttp docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp-client-reference-connectors) the Connector classes can be initiated with keyword *force_close* and the meaning is explained like so:

```
force_close (bool) – close underlying sockets after connection releasing (optional).
```

**Question:** Can I be sure that *every* request to the same host is guaranteed to happen over a newly negotiated connection when I set *force_close* to *True*?

Answer (score 1):

`force_close=True` closes a connection to client after response receiving (or on error).

The option disables [HTTP Keep-Alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) feature

Comment: Hi @Andrew Svetlov, thanks for your reply. But I don't quite get it, sorry ... could you reply concretely to the question (last line) in my post, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `force_close=True` negotiates a new connection on every request.

Comment: Please groom your answer so I can accept it and don't forget to provide a reference or so. How do you know that new connections are really negotiated with each new request ... ? (Not that I don't believe, just for the record.)